# Use different domain and URLs with web application

Tags: php, html, web-applications, url-routing

### Background

I have a web application that I host on my own server. I have clients who use the application as is, but some have asked if they can 'host' the application on their own server. This enables them to have their own URLS rather than mine. The application only forms part of their website so I'm assuming it will not be possible for my server to respond to a direct call to their domain etc

To give some examples, i currently have urls like `www.mydomain.com/profile`, `www.mydomain.com/index.php?option=someoption&view=someview&id=1` What my clients' want is `www.theirdomian.com/profile`, `www.theirdomian.com/index.php?option=someoption&view=someview&id=1` etc

### Question

My question is, what is the best way for me to allow them to use their own URLs with my application, without giving them all the backend source code and databases to install on their server?

I dont really want to allow them to 'host' my application. But do want to enable them to use their own URLs, without having to modify anything on my server.

One way I thought would be to create a router.php file that sits on their server.  When a link is clicked on the clients site, the router receives the request and modifies the url to get the data from my server etc. The route them outputs the html source back to the clients site via the calling URL.

Is this an effective way to achieve what I want, or is it way off the mark.

Comment: If you don't give them access to you code, then they don't host your application, but at best a proxy, period. What to do depends on what it exactly is that they want, what problem are they trying to solve? If it's just the feeling of having their fancy own domein, just point a DNS record of a subdomain to your server, etc.

Comment: Yes its more the 'perception' of them hosting it. So really it is a proxy. If i go the DNS route, its hassle for me and wont it affect my other users? I want to pass the responsibility to the client. I just wanted to check if my idea above is a reasonable one.

Comment: Having a serveralias in apache defined somewhere & them pointing a DNS record to your IP seems the easiest & will not effect your users save for 1 reload of your webserver config. If you want them to do all the work, just setting up apache as a proxy on their server is next easiest. No PHP need be involved, all webserver config, for which they shouldn't need your help either. You probably won't even notice if save for the requesting IP change.

Comment: Cool, but will that affect how they access pages hosted on their site? Only 20% of their pages will be for my application. Will the DNS mess up getting requests form their server?

Comment: Yes, it would, hence my suggestion for a subdomain. But their webserver could also proxy only limited urls to your server, look at the basic `ProxyPass` setting in the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the links in your site should not be hardcoded. If you have hardcoded `www.mydomain.com/...` everywhere... good luck getting it out of there. You should use URLs relative to the server root, e.g.:

```
<a href="/profile">
```

For even more flexibility, use a helper that creates URLs relative to where the app is being run from instead of hardcoding any URLs. If that's done, all you need to do to access the same site using a different domain name is to configure the web server so it accepts requests for the domain name and setup the DNS entry for `theirdomain.com` to point to your server.

If that's not an option, the guys running `theirdomain.com` should run a **reverse proxy** that serves your domain under their domain.

Comment: My urls are all relative (i can see why you thought they weren't, will modify question). Maybe my understanding is poor, but If I setup a DNS entry, wont that affect all my other users? I have over 100 clients. Most use my site but 10 or so want it integrated into their site. I want to chose a way that will result in less work for me. If i can create some simple script that they can install on their site, that's perfect, as I don't need to change anything on my server. I just need to have my proposed solution validated as reasonable really

Comment: They need to change *their* DNS entry to point to *you*. It will not affect you at all, you now simply have two domains pointing to the same server. Again, this means your web server needs be told it's responsible for this new domain as well though. The reverse proxy solution requires no work on your part at all.

Comment: Ah cool - sounds good. Sorry, another stupid question, but if they point to my server, will that mess up their other pages? No all their pages will point to my server, only about 20%.

Comment: You don't have to reverse proxy the whole domain at once. You can simply set up a reverse proxy for `theirdomain.com/yourawesomeapp`, while the rest of the domain is served from their servers.

Comment: That does sound like a good option. Only issue is that then the url will be their domain.com/yourawesomeapp/profile. As silly as it sounds, my clients have a requirement for the url to be their domain.com/profile , but i think they will need to compromise on this...

Comment: If your app has a "top page", i.e. `mydomain.com/`, they can't have their cake and eat it too. If they only need a specific number of paths, they can forward just those specific paths. That's prone to cause name clashes down the line though, namespacing it into its own "folder" is the sensible thing to do.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge customers demand all kind kind of crazy stuff, as a programmer you tell them was possible and what isn't.

Comment: @Pablo i agree, but we should at least make a reasonable attempt to make their requirements a reality

Answer (score 1):

This maybe too advanced for your needs but...

can you not create some basic API that they can tap into, this will give them the freedom to utilise in there own way, whilst at the same time you retain control of it's behaviour.

the API will need nothing more than cURL and some simple XML

there are many ways to accomplish what you want, including mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really want to go down the route of mod_rewrite as its an extra thing for me to maintain. Ideally I want to just pass the responsibility of integration to my client. An api may be a good way to go, but is my way maybe even more simple? Im really just trying to gauge if the way I have suggested is a good way to achieve what i want

Comment: Ok cool - that's what I wanted to find out - does my method suck. Regarding the API answer, its quite vague. For example my router is basically acting like an api - getHTML(urlOptions); Can you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

ok!

lets say you have a PHP file hosted at http://www.mydomain.com/listener.php

that takes in post data

```
$Data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

the posted data in this example is XML

```
<Myapp>
 <method="InitFunction"/>
 <User id="1234"/>
</Myapp>
```

the posted data here was delivered from a PHP file (i.e your API)
that simply read data from the client input (as the API is on the clients server)

the API uses cURL to post to your file i.e http://www.mydomain.com/listener.php

depedning on what happens you can then respond i.e Print or ECHO the response back to the API.

check the php.net site for usage on cURL - it's very simpy to use